# Show UITabBar without beeing RootViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm having an LoginViewController which is the RootViewController. This ViewController should not have the TabBar included. The Rest of the ViewController should contain the UITabBar, But it is not showing. If i make the tabBar the rootController it will show the tabBar in the viewcontrollers. This would also make the firsttab the rootviewcontroller which it should not.

My question is then how can i make the loginview the rootViewController without an tabBar and still show the tabBar in the other viewcontrollers?

My code:

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

MenuViewController *firstTab = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];


FixtureViewController *secondTab = [[FixtureViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FixtureViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondTab];

WorldCupViewController *thirdTab = [[WorldCupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WorldCupViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdTab];

LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];



self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController, navController2, navController3];

navController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"message-7"];
navController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"football-32"];
    navController3.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trophy-32"];
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0f green:89/255.0f blue:196/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

[self.window setRootViewController:navController4];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Do you want to show the TabBar once the user has logged in?

Comment: yes when the user is logged in it will push to the firsttab (MenuViewController). This MenuViewController wont show the uitabbar which i've created in the appdelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is transition the application from the LoginViewController to the Tabbar. What I would suggest doing is replacing the LoginViewController with the TabBar as the rootViewController.

Here is some sample code, perform this action in your AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

     LoginViewController *loginView = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *navController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginView];

     [self.window setRootViewController:navController4];
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES;
}

-(void)transitionToTabBar
{

   // Set the TabBar how you are in your sample code, this is just an example.
   [self.window setRootViewController:[[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:Nil]];

   [UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown animations:^{
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Exactly, but now it will start with the menuViewController as the rootViewController and not the loginviewController

Comment: @user3258468 no only set the LoginViewController at the rootViewController. Once the user has logged in then you send a message to the app delegate to transition to the tab bar with the sample I showed you. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use main View controller (for MenuViewController) and by using segue you can present another view controller which has TabBar in it.